# MySQL search with highest combined adjacent values

Tags: mysql, database, search

```
depth   ktim
6999.0  576.46
6999.5  892.10
7000.0   10.12
7000.5   22.07
7001.0  186.55
7001.5  577.98
7002.0  799.42
7002.5  334.15
7003.0   99.43
7003.5  111.43
7004.0   41.94
```

So I have a huge database table, the above is a simple example. Is there a way to have MySQL perform a query where it would ouput the values with the 5 highest adjacent values? I will need to adjust the query to be 5, 10, 20, etc..

So if you add up every 5 adjacent cells in the ktim column, the 5 with the highest would be 7001.0-7003.5 as that has a total ktim of 1997.53 and would output the following:

```
depth   ktim
7001.0  186.55
7001.5  577.98
7002.0  799.42
7002.5  334.15
7003.0   99.43
```

The table is sorted by depth and adjacency will always be calculated based on the depth.

Comment: Does "adjacent" always mean "different by 0.5"?

Comment: Yes, the difference in depth will always increase by 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is to get the maximum sum of 5 and where that occurs.  I appears that the depth is increasing by 0.5 as a regular sequence.  If you can depend on this, the following query will add up the first ktim values up to the current value, and then return the maximum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select SUM(ktim) from t t2 where t2.depth between t.depth - 2.25 and t.depth
             ) as lastfivesum
      from t
     ) t
order by lastfivesum
limit 1
```

This will give you the last row (`7003.0` in your example).  If you need all five, you would just join this back to the original table as int:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   (select SUM(ktim) from t t2 where t2.depth between t.depth - 2.25 and t.depth
                   ) as lastfivesum
            from t
           ) t
      order by lastfivesum
      limit 1
     ) tmax
     on t.depth bewteen tmax.depth - 2.25 and tmax.depth
```

I'm using `2.25` instead of `2` just to prevent problems with floating point numbers.

Comment: I do have 2 questions that have come up.
1) The SQL outputs a table with 2 columns of identical rows. When I output my code, the 2nd set of the column is outputted so all values are the same, how do I get the first set of columns that differ by .5. [See SQL output here.](http://hf.shawndibble.com/10.html)
2) The database has several thousand rows, but if my values are too high (25 rows for example), I get only 1 output. [See SQL output here.](http://hf.shawndibble.com/25.htm)